# Simple circle packing problem with circles of different size

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, packing

Is there an analytical solution to find the intersection point between the placed grain and grain 1 if the placed grain is lowered [in the reference frame of the image] along the dotted line? We know the radius of both circles. We have graphical figured out the intersection point and labelled it for reference in the image.

[image: schematic for circle packing]

Comment: "Draw the right triangle and the solution becomes obvious."

Comment: Yes, that was made clear by the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming

- a right angle between the dotted line and the line through the center of `g1` and `g2`
- the dotted line is a tangent of `g1`

you can use the following:

Consider the situation when `g1` and `gp` touch. In that case, the length of the line segment between center `g1` and `gp` is equal to `radius(g1) + radius(gp)`. Which is also the hypotenuse of a right-angled triangle for which `radius(g1)` is a cathetus. `arccos(radius(g1)/(radius(g1) + radius(gp)))` gives you then the angle between the hypotenuse and cathetus around the center of `g1`.

This angle and the length `radius(g1)` are polar coordinates of the intersection point relative to the center of `g1`.